# How do you change a group of notes into a tuplet in Sibelius?

Tags: sibelius

I'm trying to write this (bar is 3/8):

[image: original]

I have entered those following notes, but I want to change their values so I can add the remaining notes:

[image: sibelius]

If I select the first group, and ask for quintlet (ctrl + 5), all notes but the first one are gone. For the octolet (ctrl + 8), it won't work at all.

How to achieve this without reentering the notes ?

Comment: I never had much luck turning existing notes into part of the tuplet I want in Musescore, either (and if enough people complained about being unable to pull that off in Musescore, I'm sure someone would have updated it with the capacity to newly pull that off). I'm afraid it'll be significantly more efficient to just put in the tuplet you want right off the bat and re-enter the notes.

Comment: Is that first measure by any chance formatted as a pickup measure, with fewer than three beats? If I recall, Sibelius doesn't let you enter more notes than a measure can "hold." Also, *do* you actually want a quintuplet (5 notes in the space of one quarter note? or in the space of one 8th note?), or do you want a measure full of ordinary 16th notes, except that the very first one is a rest?

Comment: @AndyBonner Acutally it's a 5plet starting at the 2nd 8th (on second beat). Sibelius is not helpful with Liszt's music, since I have many measures with stretched durations (eg., recitative, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert an existing group into a tuplet.   Start over.  Delete all but the first chord, apply a suitable tuplet setting to it, then follow on entering the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like you'll have to use the tuplet dialog box](https://www.rpmseattle.com/of_note/create-a-tuplet-of-any-ratio-in-sibelius/) rather than keyboard shortcuts. You're looking for 5 notes in the space of two eighth notes, but Sibelius assumes it's meant to be 5 in the space of a single eighth note.

Comment: Even that web page leaves it ambiguous whether Sibelius chops off all but the first 2 notes in the tuplet after inserting the custom tuplet.